# How to extract the userkey value when %2F is present in an expression in jmeter

Tags: regex, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

I am creating a script in JMeter for performance testing!
I need to get the userkey form the
response header.
As we can see below is the short response for the same:
`&Userkey=AMfN%2Fm1wlh`

And I tried using the below regex:
`Userkey=(.+?)\n`
`Userkey=(.+?)%2F(.+?)\n`
But didn't got solution using post processor, i.e. regular expression extractor in JMeter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following regular expression:

```
Userkey=(.*)
```

Where:

- `.` - matches any character
- `*` - repetition
- `()` - grouping

As you can see it produces a match in "RegExp Tester" mode of the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener:

[image]

More information:

- [Apache JMeter - Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)

Comment: How to use in the http request, as it will not take %2F in parameterization.